# Multiple MCs, Single Listener, AsBroadcaster

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I'm currently working trying to have multiple MCs inside a container MC which when they mini MCs are clicked will broadcast a message so that I can act upon them.  This would be simple in AS 3 as it would be mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, obj); however, this is AS 2 and so I am semi-forced to use the broadcastMessage('myMessage'); and mc.addListener(obj); event handler.

The main problem is that the broadcaster isn't broadcasting any messages.

The second problem is that there are 5 MCs and when I click one of them, I get 5 trace messages about the click.  I can't seem to keep the MC clicks unique even though they are all given separate instance names vie the properties panel.

Any help would be appreciated.

A link to my code is [here (pastie.org #481511)](http://pastie.org/481511).  Can you see anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've got it half answered.  I was missing a "this" before the broadcastMessage() call so once I changed it to this.broadcastMessage('myMessage', this) it started working.

Still have the issue with 5 different instances (i.e. dragged-&-dropped 5 times from the library and named them different instance names) of one movie clip all calling the same broadcast message at the same time.  I get the following output:

```
Object: _level0.instance1.photo5
Object: _level0.instance1.photo4
Object: _level0.instance1.photo3
Object: _level0.instance1.photo2
Object: _level0.instance1.photo1
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Ended up having to use the hitTest() method to see if the click was within a specific movieclip or not.